# Modify a Crystal Report document after publishing it (C#)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I created a test `report.rpt` and give some static label "test" using C# (web app), and it show normally in my local pc, after publishing to server (IIS) it show normally also.

Is there any way to modify my label "test" to "test 0" without re-publishing the app ? if yes is it safe to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so.. If it was a database field from like sql, you could just update that. But a fixed label won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change text objects in code but, first, please explain why you need this. With more context, it would be easier to provide an informed answer. 
For example, perhaps you can simply use a parameter to control the content. 
Or perhaps you should simply open the report in Crystal and change the design...
Too many guesses without more context.